# Power BI Embedded & JavaScript - How can I apply an action afterf a slicerState change on a particular visual?

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a report that contains a custom toggle visual.  The toggle has two possible values,  "OFF" (by default) or "ON"

What I would like to do is link that toggle value to a report theme change.  So when the value of that toggle value changes,  the report theme will update to either light or dark mode.

I'm at a stage where I can get the slicerState of the particular visual and determine it's value as being on or off.  However, when trying to apply a report theme update,  it appears to loop endlessly (   ([see recording here](https://vimeo.com/628252723)))

My feeling is that it's related to the report.on('rendered'....... function but I'm looking to get a bit of help if possible.   With it being a custom visual, I'm unable to listen to a buttonClick or dataSelection (as far as i'm aware),  so i guess the only way I can detect that the toggle has been used is to track the slicerState function?

here's is the block of code relating to what i'm trying to do:

```
    // Get a reference to the embedded dashboard HTML element
var $embedContainer = $("#embedContainer");

//define report embed
var report = powerbi.embed($embedContainer.get(0), config);



//when report renders
report.on('rendered', async () => {

//get all pages
  const pages = await report.getPages()

  //get active page
  let activePage = pages.filter(function(page) {
    return page.isActive
  })[0];

//get visuals on active page
  let visuals = await activePage.getVisuals();

//find target visual
  const TargetVisual = visuals.filter(function(visual) {
    return visual.name === "259fea6751434e7910b4" 
  })[0];

//get current state of visual 
  const state = await TargetVisual.getSlicerState();
  
  
//get current state value (on or off )
let filteredValue = state.filters[0].values
 
  console.log(filteredValue)
  
  
  //when the toggle is switched ON,  apply the light theme.
    if (filteredValue == "ON")   {
    
    
  
  /*
      //when clickon on 
      report.applyTheme({
      themeJson: themes.find(theme => theme.name === "dark")
    }); }  else {
    
    
    
     //when the toggle is switched OFF,  apply the dark theme.
       //when clickon off 
      report.applyTheme({
      themeJson: themes.find(theme => theme.name === "light")
    });
    */
    }
```

........

```
 var themes = [
    
      {
        "name": "light",
        "dataColors": ["#93A299", "#CF543F", "#B5AE53", "#848058", "#E8B54D", "#786C71", "#93A2A0", "#CF9A3F", "#8CB553", "#728458", "#D0E84D", "#786D6C"],
        "background": "#FFFFFF",
        "foreground": "#CF543F",
        "tableAccent": "#93A299"
      },
        {
            "name": "dark",
            "dataColors": ["#31B6FD", "#4584D3", "#5BD078", "#A5D028", "#F5C040", "#05E0DB", "#3153FD", "#4C45D3", "#5BD0B0", "#54D028", "#D0F540", "#057BE0"],
            "background": "#000000",
            "foreground": "#4584D3",
            "tableAccent": "#31B6FD"
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to track the slicer state which is applied at the runtime in Power BI embed. `getSlicerState` will give you an empty array of filters if you change the state of slicer at runtime. If you set the slicer state at compile time using `setSlicerState` then `getslicerState` will give you an array of filters and using that you can apply the theme.

```js
if (state.filters.length > 0) { 
            report.applyTheme({
                themeJson: themes.find(theme => theme.name === "dark")
            });
```

Please find the references:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Power-BI-Embedded-Tracking-visual-filters-slicers/m-p/802196

https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/control-report-slicers